# how to set directory in ydl_opts in using youtube-dl in python?

Tags: python-2.7, youtube-api, youtube-dl

```
**
```

What do i need to add to specify that all the download mp3 will go to this directory: e:/python/downloadedsongs

```
ydl_opts = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'download_archive': 'downloaded_songs.txt',
    'outtmpl': '%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'postprocessors': [{
        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
        'preferredquality': '192',
        }],
    'logger': MyLogger(),
    'progress_hooks': [my_hook],

}
```

if i understand it correctly outtmpl is for the template of the name of output file. 
**

Answer (score 30, accepted):

outtmpl can contain directory names, simply set

```
'outtmpl': 'e:/python/downloadedsongs/%(title)s.%(ext)s',
```

Comment: How can we specify username and password?

Comment: @PrashantBhanarkar That's a separate question. Feel free to ask it on stackoverflow!  Make sure you review the [list of available options](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L128-L278) beforehand.