# Download YouTube video using Python to a certain directory

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have tried the following code to download a video in YouTube and it is working, but I want to save the video at a particular location. Now it is saving the video in `C:/Users/Download`. If I want to save the video in  the desktop, what changes do I need in the code?

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl
import urllib
import shutil
ydl_opts = {}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n06H7OcPd-g'])
```

Comment: Actually, the answer to that question is to add `-o` option to the command line in order to set your output file, refer to [GitHub example](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl#output-template-examples).

Comment: simply set 'outtmpl' in `ydl_opts`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35643757/how-to-set-directory-in-ydl-opts-in-using-youtube-dl-in-python

Answer (score 94):

I found out a really cool python module that allows you to download videos from youtube easily. TO install it:

```
pip install pytube
```

Now, You can download your video like this -

```
from pytube import YouTube
yt = YouTube("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n06H7OcPd-g")
yt = yt.get('mp4', '720p')
yt.download('/path/to/download/directory')
```

Boom, Now you can easily scrape such videos using Python easily; Now, We Drink!

## Update 1:

Thanks to @Chiramisu's comment, You can use the following one-liner to download the highest quality video:

```
YouTube('video_url').streams.first().download('save_path')
```

For Windows, please specify path with double backslashes ex:

```
YouTube('video_url').streams.first().download('C:\\Users\\username\\save_path')
```

## Update 2:

If pytube doesn't seem to work for you, try using youtube-dl:

```
pip install --upgrade youtube-dl
```

Now Download Videos:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {}
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BaW_jenozKc'])
```

More info on ytdl in python [here](https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#embedding-youtube-dl).

Comment: i don't understand where the video variable/object came from?

Comment: pytube is very slow, how other online  platforms are able to download it so fast ?? I have a very fast 16 Mbps connection, but its downloading at the speed of 512 kbps or so

Comment: `AttributeError: 'YouTube' object has no attribute 'get' `

Comment: @Vallie vist there repository on GitHub

Comment: One-liner [updated logic](https://github.com/nficano/pytube#getting-started): `YouTube('video_url').streams.first().download('save_path')`. This will download highest quality video, but 1080p or above will be separate files for video and audio which will need to be joined with FFmpeg or some such utility.

Comment: I'm getting the same error too here. 

`AttributeError: 'YouTube' object has no attribute 'get' `

Comment: @DakshMiglani I'm getting an error: `KeyError: 's'`

Comment: I'll check in a bit

Comment: @DakshMiglani pytube seems really broken.  `Key error title` among others listed on Github and fixes provided to edit source code files but the recommended install method is `pip install pytube` so that does not give us source code right?  What do you suggest?

Comment: @mLstudent33 check the udpate 2 in my answer

Comment: `YouTube('video_url').streams.first()` didn't get me the highest res. I solved it with `yt.streams.filter(res="1080p").first().download()`

Comment: @JohnFunk well the best solution is to use ytdl imo.

Comment: When installing pytube at 9.6.0, YouTube module cannot be imported with the error message 'ImportError: cannot import name urlencode'

Comment: First best quality: `YouTube('video_url').streams.filter(progressive=True).order_by('resolution').desc().first().download('target_dir')`

Answer (score 27):

downloading videos from youtube in python 3.x
for the reference you can check https://python-pytube.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart.html#downloading-a-video

```
from pytube import YouTube
import os

def downloadYouTube(videourl, path):

    yt = YouTube(videourl)
    yt = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').order_by('resolution').desc().first()
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)
    yt.download(path)

downloadYouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zNyYDHCg06c', './videos/FindingNemo1')
```

Comment: I think your code is probably fine but I'm getting a `KeyError: s`, seems like an open issue on github.

Answer (score 13):

You should put it inside `ydl_opts`:

```py
ydl_opts = {
    'outtmpl': os.path.join(download_path, '%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s'),
}
```

In your case, `download_path` should be `'C:/Users/Desktop'`. Use `%(title)s.%(ext)s` instead of `%(title)s-%(id)s.%(ext)s` if you prefer a file name without video ID.

Or you can just `os.chdir(path)` to change the directory to where you want the download to be before you start your download.

```py
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl
import os

ydl_opts = {}
os.chdir('C:/Users/Desktop')
with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n06H7OcPd-g'])
```

Comment: if I want to save the file on google cloud storage, can i still define the path using os.chdir, such that the downloaded video could be saved in gcs.

Comment: Do you have access to gcs in File Explorer/Finder? If so, probably yes. I can save files directly in my google drive, which is mounted as a volume on my mac.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted. Rest of the answers are too focused on other packages while the OP clearly mentioned youtube-dl.

Answer (score 4):

```
Path = "The Path That You Want"
Location = '%s \%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s'.replace("%s ", Path)
ytdl_format_options = {
'outtmpl': Location
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options) as ydl:
     ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n06H7OcPd-g'])
```

I personally don't know the library very well, but here is my knowledge the youtube_dl have ytdl_format_options it gives you the options to add some I don't know what it called but let say parameters like above outtmp1 give you the option to specify the location, id, title, or quiet to see the log or not and there is so much more. almost everything you can get it from this URL:https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#format-selection

Comment: Please include an explanation about this code you have posted.

Comment: This is the correct answer, it should have more upvotes. I wonder if there is a way to obtain the name of the downloaded file for further processing.

Answer (score 4):

**-> Uninstall pytube (if is present)**

```
pip uninstall pytube
```

**-> Install:**

```
pip install pytube3
```

**-> Modify extract.py in environment:**

```
lib/pytube/extract.py
```

**-> Find and edit line:**

```
parse_qs(formats[i]["cipher"]) for i, data in enumerate(formats)
```

**-> change it to:**

```
parse_qs(formats[i]["signatureCipher"]) for i, data in enumerate(formats)
```

**-> Use pytube:**

```
from pytube import YouTube
import os


def downloadYoutube(vid_url, path):
    yt = YouTube(vid_url)
    yt = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').order_by('resolution').desc().first()
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)

    yt.download(path)

url = input('Input url:\n')
path = input('Path to store file:\n')
downloadYoutube(url, path)
```

Answer (score 2):

`youtube_dl` has a giant list of options: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/youtube_dl/YoutubeDL.py#L128-L278

But I don't see any that control the output directory.  So you can move the file afterward.  For that, see: [How to move a file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8858008/how-to-move-a-file-in-python).

Comment: I have tried the following code                                                   source =     'C:\Users\Sharmili Nag\Aahatein - Agnee (splitsvilla 4 theme song) Best audio quality-n06H7OcPd-g.mp4'
destination = 'C:\Users\Sharmili Nag\Desktop'
import os
os.rename(source,destination) but i am getting this error SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in positio
n 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Answer (score 2):

It will save the file **where your .py application is in**. for example, if your .py program is in your desktop folder and you run your app from the desktop, the output will save on your desktop. the only thing you need is to save your .py file in Desktop and then open a command line and go in Desktop using cd command after it run your .py file using python YOURAPP.py
but if you want to download it and then save it in another place, you need to download it like you do now (in your temporary place) then **moves it** via file libraries in python.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like pytube has changed a little bit since the top answer for the question was originally posted. Here is an updated example for working with PyTube v11.0.2 (January 9th, 2022):

```
'''
HOW TO: Download YouTube Videos Programmatically with Python & pytube

$ pip install pytube

$ python3 download.py
'''

from pytube import YouTube

def on_progress(stream, chunk, bytes_remaining):
    print("Downloading...")

def on_complete(stream, file_path):
    print("Download Complete")

yt = YouTube(
        "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ",
        on_progress_callback=on_progress,
        on_complete_callback=on_complete,
        use_oauth=False,
        allow_oauth_cache=True
    )

yt.streams.filter(file_extension='mp4', res="720p").first().download()
```

Comment: How to save the video to the user downloads directory , if the user has a mobile phone , how to save the video into the phone ?

Comment: pytube is broken above code produces  
KeyError: 'streamingData'

Answer (score 2):

I did some changes in the answer of @orlov_dumitru and it worked fine.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
from pytube import YouTube



def downloadYoutube(vid_url, path):
    yt = YouTube(vid_url)
    yt = yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').order_by('resolution').desc().first()
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.makedirs(path)

    yt.download(path)


# video url
url = sys.argv[1]
# path to where you want to save the video
path = sys.argv[2]
downloadYoutube(url, path)
exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {
    'outtmpl': 'yourPathToDirectory/%(title)s.%(ext)s',

}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XpYGgtrMTYs'])
```

`ydl_opts` is the what we need to play with. We can declare multiple attributes/parameters inside this for customisation. For this example, I've added a single attribute `outtmpl` which is used to define custom directory. We can further customize this to declare *filename*, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip3 install pytube

    
yt_url = "https://youtu.be/k8oMuLWiUzo"
from pytube import YouTube
yt = YouTube(yt_url)
yt.streams.filter(progressive=True, file_extension='mp4').order_by('resolution').desc().first().download()
```

Answer (score -5):

I guess you are a bit confused, try this code, end to end

```
    from __future__ import unicode_literals
    import youtube_dl
    import urllib
    import shutil
    ydl_opts = {}
    with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
        ydl.download(['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n06H7OcPd-g'])

    #Moving your source file to destination folder
    source_file = 'C:\Users\Sharmili Nag\Aahatein - Agnee (splitsvilla 4 theme song) Best audio quality-n06H7OcPd-g.mp4'
    destination_folder = 'C:\Users\Sharmili Nag\Desktop\Aahatein - Agnee (splitsvilla 4 theme song) Best audio quality-n06H7OcPd-g.mp4'
    shutil.move(source_file, destination_folder)
```

In case this code worked out for you, kindly mark the answer as correct.