# python youtube-dl output file not in unicode?

Tags: python, unicode, youtube-dl

Is there anyway to get the `youtube-dl.extract_info()` function to use unicode when creating the output file?

I have encountered the problem that if you download something with unicode characters like `|` in the title then the output file name will not have the same character. It will be replaced with `_` instead.

Take this [song title](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMAOnScOyGE&index=2&list=PLFASUPlhzZJjhuSIm0lAiStx3yXzSvebd&t=0s) for example.
If I download it with youtube-dl then I get this file name `【Nightcore】→ Pretty Girl _ Lyrics-dMAOnScOyGE`. Same thing happens with different kind of characters.

Is there any way to stop this?
Because it's a annoying if you want do do anything with that file afterwards.

To get the new file name I would need to do something like os.listdir(dir) to get the file. So it's not impossible to get the new file name, but I am just interested if there is a easier way.

Comment: Won't this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40713268/download-youtube-video-using-python

Comment: would if I wanted to change the download path, but I also need to rename the file, so I don't think that would fully solve the problem. But I appreciate the quick help :)

Comment: It’s nothing to do with “Unicode”, `|` is an ASCII character (as well as a Unicode character, like any other character). YTDL just ensures that paths won’t cause issues; a pipe is a special character in many contexts. You generally want a *predictable path*, or figure out exactly what file it created.

Comment: so there is no way to turn it off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The encoding of `|` to `_` is hardcoded in [`sanitize_filename` in `youtube_dl/utils.py`](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/835e45abab88e2a1661b86be255e06323e88ec7a/youtube_dl/utils.py#L483-L521). You can turn it off programatically by substituting `youtube_dl.utils.sanitize_filename` with your own implementation.

However, doing so is not recommended, and not supported out of the box. This is because `|` is an invalid character on Windows and can be used to execute arbitrary commands if expanded in a buggy script.

Insecure filenames were supported at one time, but I removed them from youtube-dl because too many people were shooting themselves in the foot, and often reported problems that clearly would have let any attacker execute arbitrary code on their machines.