# How to take user Input of file downloading path using pytube

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytube

I have made a Youtube Downloader but unable to save the video according to the path input by the user ; below is my code . Kindly refer this , I have edited the code. I am trying to make a GUI YT video downloader and I have imported every pre requisite libraries and when I do in video.download(path) , I get an error class is not defined and when I add inverted commas to it it automatically creates a new folder named *PATH*

```
from tkinter import *
from pytube import YouTube
from tkinter import filedialog

root = Tk()
root.geometry('800x600')
root.resizable(0,0)
root.title("YouTube Video Downloader")
def browseFiles():
    path = filedialog.askdirectory()
    location = '"' + path + '"'
    print(location)


Label(root,text = 'Youtube Video Downloader', font ='arial 20 bold').pack()
Label(root , text = 'Choose directory' , font = 'arial 20 bold').place(x =120, y=190)

button_explore = Button(text = "Choose directory" , command = browseFiles)

link = StringVar()

Label(root, text = 'Paste your Link Here:', font = 'calibri 25 bold').place(x= 250 , y = 50)
link_enter = Entry(root, width = 90,textvariable = link).place(x = 120, y = 110)



#syntax to download video from youtube


def Downloader():
     
    link1 =YouTube(str(link.get()))
    video = link1.streams.filter(res = "1080p").first()
    video.download(r'path')
    Label(root, text = 'DOWNLOADED', font = 'calibri 20').place(x= 180 , y = 210)  


Button(root,text = 'DOWNLOAD', font = 'calibri 15 bold' ,bg = 'firebrick1', padx = 2, command = Downloader).place(x=300 ,y =350)
button_exit = Button(text = "Exit" , command = exit)
button_exit.place(x= 250,y=500)
button_explore.place(x = 120, y= 240)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Without more information its tough to know exactly why, but I used to have a similar problem and I fixed it by writing my path like `save(r'path')`

Comment: can you please briefly explain it

Comment: The 'r' is a string prefix, which means the string that follows is a raw string. You need this so that windows reads the backslashes in your path. The backslash is otherwise an 'escaped character'

So I would try writing, video.download(r'path')

Comment: The [Python Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) does a good job of explaining what these string prefixes do.

Comment: hello Julian , I have added my full code , u can refer to it 
thanks for your help ,

Comment: using 'r' prefix doesnt work it just created a new folder named path

Comment: Where you write `video.download(r'path')`, python can't read what the selected path is in a string, and path isn't a stored variable. Have the user select the path and save it as a variable 'path'. Then use the format function ie. `video.download(r'{}'.format(path))`
That is how I would go by doing it.

Comment: If that doesn't work checkout this [web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40713268/download-youtube-video-using-python-to-a-certain-directory/54163735)

Comment: can you please write the exact code , as what ur saying about the user select the path and save it as a variable path like that please

Comment: video.download(r'{}'.format(location))
NameError: name 'location' is not defined 
getting this error

Comment: In your `def browseFiles():`, you save the path to a variable 'location'. You would have to call that variable like `video.download(r' + location + ')` or `video.download(r'{}'.format(location))` (I am not totally sure on the syntax).

Comment: I would write the code but I don't know to work with that function. 
The problem you are having is that you are letting the user select the path in the directory, but then you aren't calling the actual path when you save, you are just saving it in a folder 'path'. You need to call the variable, but when I try to call location it doesn't recognize the variable outside of the function. If you write `video.downloader(r'C:\Users\User\Desktop')` it saves the video to your desktop, So everything else works. You just need to find a way to adjust your function so that you can call the path variable.